# Attributes are not saved in gpkg from geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, geopackage

I am trying to save geopandas dataframe into .gpkg while attributes are not shown when I open with qgis.

I have tried:

```
filename = f'{layer_name}_{timestr}.gpkg'
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(layer_feature['features'], crs="EPSG:4326")
columns = gdf.columns.tolist()
columns.remove('geometry')
 gdf[columns] = gdf[columns].apply(lambda x: str(x))
 gdf.to_file(filename,  driver='GPKG')
```

I converted to str data type of column data

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: @Taras no i do not receive any errors. I receive geopackage file, but when I open with sqlite browser, I do not see columns other than geom and fid

Comment: @BERA updated the code

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

You are corrupting/destroying the dataframe with
`df[columns] = df[columns].apply(lambda x: str(x))`:

You set the columns to the value of the entire dataframe converted to weird strings.

List the columns you want to convert explicitly so you dont include the geometry column etc and use [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```
columns_to_convert = ["column1", "column2"]
df[columns_to_convert] = df[columns_to_convert].astype(str)
```

(I dont know why you would need to convert the data to strings? Geopackages can handle most data types)